# Invalid block tag - bootstrap-form, expected endblock

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-bootstrap3

I am working on a django project, but for some reason the template I am using brings up an invalid block tag error. I have looked at some other similar questions, but nothing seems helpful, so if you can see the problem please do tell me.Here is the template:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block header %}
    <h2>Register an account.</h2>
{% endblock header %} 

{% block content %}

    <form method="post" action="{% url 'users:register' %}" class="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap-form form %}

        {% buttons %}
            <button name="sumbit" class="btn btn-primary">register</button>
        {% endbuttons %}

        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}" />
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Thanks,
Milo

Comment: What about removing the `content` from `{% endblock content %}` and `header` from `{% endblock header %}`?

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunatly

Comment: Just a small typo. Nothing more!

Comment: Please select one of the below answers as accepted (although they are the same!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. It's `{% bootstrap_form form %}`, not `{% bootstrap-form form %}`

Check it [here](http://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templatetags.html#bootstrap-form)

Answer (score 1):

`{% bootstrap-form form %}` should be `{% bootstrap_form form %}`. Also paste the error

Answer (score 0):

Also for everyone else that have this same error and it's not a typo like OP did, make sure you have loaded bootstrap in your child template via

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load bootstrapX %}
```

Where X is your version of bootstrap , So it's not sufficent to load it in the base template.In addition to that make sure the load bootstrap statment is after the `extends` statment, This video explains the setup in great detail https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YmJ0TACm8oE